# Codeignither Syntax Explanation uri_segment

Tags: codeigniter-3

Can someone please explain this syntax `$this->uri->segment(3);` to me its use and relevance  in Codeignither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$this->uri->segment(n);` is used to get some parts of the url which in some situations can be really handy. One of them could be:

if you have an `url` like this:

```
http://example.com/users/profile/1
```

You could do:

```
$this->uri->segment(3); //the third segment starting from /users so counting begin after the domain name
```

in order to get the passed profile id and use this in your controller or model